# exchange server admin privileges and what he can do

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2007, exchange-2003, exchange-2013

I want to know if exchange admin can edit sent emails subject of other content from any inbox.
I also want to know what can the admin do to our emails.
regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An administrator can do anything they like.

Send As permissions aren't there by default, but they can grant the permission and then send the message.

Similarly they can grant themselves permissions to any mailbox and do anything they like to it.

However that is their job - to admin the mailboxes.

Comment: thanks Sembee, so he can change the content on any message in my inbox?

Comment: If they have permissions they can change message properties.  This doesn't mean they can just screw around in Outlook and change message contents or subject, though.  If the administrator has permissions to a mailbox, this will be visible through the `Get-MailboxPermission` (or, `Get-MailboxFolderPermission`) cmdlet in Exchange Powershell.  Simply by being an admin one does not have access to edit a mailbox.

Comment: what if he edit the message html file and change its contents?

Comment: I would say that it is very highly unlikely that anyone would get into the Exchange mailbox database and edit the contents of a mail message.  That's some pretty serious knowledge right there.

Comment: Really? You don't need access to the database. If you are an admin of the server just grant yourself Full Mailbox Access and then open the mailbox in Outlook and edit away. Very trivial to do which is why we have journaling.

Comment: That's correct. You'll often hear IT folks say that with great power comes great responsibility because administrators have total access. Granted, forging emails in someones' mailbox wouldn't be that hard. Export the user's mailbox to a pst, open it with your Outlook, set some data with forged metadata in the header. Export from outlook to PST. Upload the PST to the mailbox database and overwrite the current mailbox.